# How to extract MOOV atom/metadata from MP4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, quicktime

Can one "dump"/extract the MOOV atom from an MP4 file? If so, how? Hoping for an obscure FFMPEG command.

I need to be able to process/play a stream without searching for the MOOV atom over and over again. For very long streams, this can run into several megabytes of data. It's rather strange, I don't think the MOOV atom is huge, I just think that it is scattered thruout the first N megabytes (i.e. toplevel data at the begnning, with references to further atoms that are later in the stream).

Thus, it would make sense for me to extract the MOOV atom out of the file, keep it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [AtomicParsley](http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/) to parse the metadata of a MP4-file. For example

```
 AtomicParsley /path/to.mp4 -T 1
```

will print the whole atom tree.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but I'd use [bento4 mp4dump](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dump/), it's really easy to install on mac with brew `brew install bento4`

```
mp4dump 1.mp4 

[ftyp] size=8+16
  major_brand = iso5
  minor_version = 200
  compatible_brand = iso6
  compatible_brand = mp41
[moov] size=8+740
  [mvhd] size=12+96
    timescale = 1000
    duration = 0
    duration(ms) = 0
....
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `qtfaststart -l fileName` which outputs something more human readable like :

```
$ qtfaststart -l myFile.mp4
ftyp (32 bytes)
free (8 bytes)
mdat (283805466 bytes)
moov (3541465 bytes)
```

The Python `qtfaststart` is different from the `qt-faststart` binary (bundled with `ffmpeg`)  and can be installed using this command:

```
sudo -H $(which pip) install qtfaststart
```

`qtfaststart` command line arguments :

```
$ qtfaststart -h
Usage: qtfaststart [options] infile [outfile]

Options:
  --version     show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help    show this help message and exit
  -d, --debug   Enable debug output
  -l, --list    List top level atoms
  -s, --sample  Create a small sample of the input file
```

The `qtfaststart` sources are [here](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart)

Comment: On my Mac, where I get all these nifty utilities with `brew`, the command is actually `qt-faststart` and is part of the `ffmpeg` package.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn qt-faststart is a binary program but qtfaststart is a Python program, they have different command line arguments. I don't a Mac at hand so I cannot help you anyfurther than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319) or with [brew-pip](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/brew-pip)

Comment: Thanks so much, @SebMa, you're quite right — there is indeed a difference — but unfortunately `brew` and `brew-pip` don't seem to like `qtfaststart`; apparently, there is a conflict somewhere between the `brew`-provided package, and the package provided by `pip` itself (i.e. `brew` believes both to be the same). `easy_install qtfaststart` will work with the system's Python (2.7.X in macOS Catalina).

Comment: Unfortunately this only list "top level atoms", not the whole tree